# PostgreSQL query using GROUP BY question

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0

I have a polygon layer table in PostgreSQL  and I want to create a simple query using `GROUP BY` .

Here my fields :

```
fid   field1
--    ----
1     text1
1     text2
1     text3
2     text1
3     text4
4     text10
8     text1
1     text15
9     text20
9     text20
```

I want to use a PostGIS spatial query to group by my layer with `fid` field
but i need to keep all unique values from `field1`

Here an example where i want for export after query :

```
fid   field1
--    ----
1     text1,text2,text3
2     text1
3     text4
4     text10
8     text1
1     text15
9     text20
```

i try this Query :

```
SELECT fid,field1 FROM public.mytable GROUP BY fid
```

but I don't know how to keep all unique values from `field1`.

Any idea ?

Comment: Pure SQL questions without geospatial content are more appropriately asked over in  [dba.se].

Answer (score 1):

You need an [aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-aggregate.html). In this cas string_agg() should do it. First argument is the field to aggregate, second argument is the delimiter.

```
SELECT a.fid, string_agg(a.field1, ', ')
FROM 
   (SELECT DISTINCT b.fid, b.field1 FROM public.mytable AS b) AS a

GROUP BY a.fid;
```

This is generic to PostgreSQL, not just PostGIS.

Comment: that keep unique values from field 1 ?

Comment: It will aggregate every value in `field1` that has a common value in `fid` column.

Comment: yes but i need unique values and not duplicate like this :

`1     text1,text2,text1` i need like this `1     text1,text2` in this case

Comment: I've updated my answer. Not texted or though. Basically build a sub table eliminating any duplicates, and then query that. There may be faster ways.

Comment: first need to work after we can look for faster way,do you have test it ?look nice I will test it soon but I am not sure if `DISTINCT` help in our case.that remove duplicate records right ?

Comment: No. I've not tested it. Apologies for typos in previous comment. On my phone!

Comment: I am from phone me too I cant test it now

Comment: Why not just `str_agg(DISTINCT a.field1, ', ' )` instead of subquery?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fid, string_agg(field1, ', ')
FROM public.mytable
GROUP BY fid
```

Comment: that keep unique values from field 1 ?

Comment: yes did you try?

Comment: not yet but tutorial say i think say `string_agg`  keep all values right ?